What's the first stage gain in this noise figure?
Determine the noise figure of the circuit shown in Fig. 2.53(a). Neglect transistor capacitances, flicker noise, channel-length modulation, and body effect.

The author assumed that first stage gain \$A_{v1} = - g_{m1} R_{D1}\$. however, I disagree.
\$R_{D1}\$ and \$1/g_{m2}\$ are in parallel.

$$A_{v1} = -g_{m1} \biggl(R_{D1} \parallel \frac{1} {g_{m2}} \biggl)$$

Please read the text thoroughly before asking a question. According to equation (2.126),


the author is decomposing the equivalent resistance into \$R_{out_1}\$ and \$R_{in_2}\$ and considering the effect of both of them separately. In other words, according to the example, the unloaded gain is \$-g_{m_1}R_{D_1}\$, and why that method works is justified in the derivation of the equation (2.126). Then he gets:

It is completely explained and derived in the text just a couple of pages before.
[Source: Behzad Razavi, RF Microelectronics, chapter 2, pages 53-56]
